# cubic function, $ x^3-2x^2-4x=5$

Tags: functions, polynomials

If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the three roots of the cubic function, $ x^3-2x^2-4x=5$, find the value of β +  + β.
I know that there is a way to calculate the $\alpha \beta  + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma$ with something that uses $\alpha + \beta + \gamma$ or $\alpha\beta\gamma$ but I can't find that.

Comment: Try expanding the expression $(x - \alpha) (x - \beta) (x-\gamma)$ and then comparing coefficients with $x^3-2x^2-4x-5$.

Answer (score 3):

$\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ satisfies $$x^3-2x^2-4x-5=0$$

Using [Vieta's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we know that $$\alpha \beta +\beta \gamma+\gamma \alpha= -4$$
As $-4$ is the coefficient of $x$. So we are done.